# How to change wordpress text for invalid password on password protected pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have password protected pages and when someone enters a wrong password this text comes up "You've entered an invalid password."

How can I change this text to read something else?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to find out what page it is first e.g. passwordpage.php in the directory of wordpress. You then need to change the javascript that is outputting the error. This can be done by opening the file which contains the javascript error and then search for "You've entered an invalid password". You will then need to change the text to your required text. Send the link of the page that is outputting the javascript alert for me and I can find which file needs to be edited :)

Comment: @ZarkoZivkovic That is done by a form, it isn't a javascript alert. If you look for where the submit button is with the value of "validate". It should be in the php/htm page for that URL. I can't access the php file directly because of the .htaccess changing the URL so if you know what page that form is on edit it on there